# create a df using max() and adding its corresponding value in adjacent column

Tags: python, pandas

I have merged 2 dataframes as shown

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ref':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14],'value1':[76,23,43,34,0,78,34],'value2':[1,45,8,0,76,45,56]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ref':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14],'value1_pair':[0,0,0,0,180,180,90],'value2_pair':[0,0,0,0,90,180,90]})
```

Output: `df=df1.merge(df2, on='ref')`

```
   ref  value1  value2  value1_pair  value2_pair
0    2      76       1            0            0
1    4      23      45            0            0
2    6      43       8            0            0
3    8      34       0            0            0
4   10       0      76          180           90
5   12      78      45          180          180
6   14      34      56           90           90
```

Output: `df['value1'].max()`

```
78
```

However this is only for column `value1`. How can I repeat this for `value2` column (my real df will have many columns) and then combine their corresponding value pair into a new df?

Desired Output:

```
 ref            12   10
value1          78   76    
value1_pair     180  90
```

Comment: Can you explain what those columns are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is many pairs `valueN_x` with `valueN-y` you can convert `ref` to index, then split columns by `_` , reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and get rows with maximal `v` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ref':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14],'value1_x':[76,23,43,34,0,78,34],'value2_x':[1,45,8,0,76,45,56]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ref':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14],'value1_y':[0,0,0,0,180,180,90],'value2_y':[0,0,0,0,90,180,90]})

df=df1.merge(df2, on='ref')
print (df)
   ref  value1_x  value2_x  value1_y  value2_y
0    2        76         1         0         0
1    4        23        45         0         0
2    6        43         8         0         0
3    8        34         0         0         0
4   10         0        76       180        90
5   12        78        45       180       180
6   14        34        56        90        90
```

---

```
df = df.set_index('ref')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

print(df.columns.levels[1])
#Index(['x', 'y'], dtype='object')

df = df.stack(0)
df = df.loc[df.groupby(level=1)['x'].idxmax()].reset_index(level=0).T
print (df)
#      value1  value2
# ref      12      10
# x        78      76
# y       180      90
```

EDIT: For sorting columns extract numbers and get positions of sorted values by `argsort()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'M1':list('abcdef'),
         'M10':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'M2':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'M3':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'M11':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'M4':list('aaabbb')
})

df =df.iloc[:, df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).argsort()]
print (df)
  M1  M2  M3 M4  M10  M11
0  a   7   1  a    4    5
1  b   8   3  a    5    3
2  c   9   5  a    4    6
3  d   4   7  b    5    9
4  e   2   1  b    5    2
5  f   3   0  b    4    4
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael: Thanks for this. I will investigate this and see does it work on my real df!

Comment: @user9106985 - What are `print (df.columns)` after `merge` in real df?

Comment: I think the print is too big to put here in comment but it is basically 53 columns, 
1st col is 'ref', 
1st group is 26 columns of  'value' which we apply idxmax 
3rd group of 26 columns are the corresponding pairs
I get an error: KeyError: 'Column not found: v'

Comment: How looks `print(df.columns.tolist()[:3])` after `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` ?

Comment: [('M1', 'x'), ('M2', 'x'), ('M3', 'x')]

Comment: @user9106985 - And `print(df.columns.levels[1])` ?

Comment: @I think after `df.columns = df.columns.split(...` , it is something like `Index(['pair', 'x'], dtype='object')` ?

Comment: print(df.columns.tolist()[:3]) gives [('M1', 'x'), ('M2', 'x'), ('M3', 'x')] the so called values to be operated on.
print(df.columns.tolist()[26:29]) gives [('M1', 'y'), ('M2', 'y'), ('M3', 'y')] these are the so called pairs

Comment: @user9106985 - answe was edited - also input data. Now it is simplier, because removed `rename`

Comment: Great this works. Thanks for the new ideas! How would I change the ordering of the resulting 26 columns. at the moment it goes like ` M1, M10, M11....M2...`
I would like `M1, M2…M26`